# JSON2XML : Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

My error is `**SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Content is not allowed in prolog**.` I have using `Windows-10` and `saxon9.jar` file. How to resolve this error?

In my `command prompt` i have using:

`java -cp saxonb9\saxon9-7.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:"init" -xsl:"simple3.xsl" -s:"simple3.json"`

My `JSON` is:

`{"analystId": "Test","jobId": "","profileData": {"allAuthorCoverage": false,"assetClasses": [{`"code": "Test1"}]} }
`

MY `XSLT` is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" /> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="jsonText"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template name="init">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/> 
  </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[@key]" >
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide precise details on how you use or call Saxon when you get that error.

Comment: @MartinHonnen; I have updated my question. Please check and advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `-s` option as it is only usable for XML input. So use

```
java -cp saxonb9\saxon9-7.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:"init" -xsl:"simple3.xsl"
```

As you have declared `<xsl:param name="jsonText"`, I think you also want to pass in the param

```
java -cp saxonb9\saxon9-7.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:"init" -xsl:"simple3.xsl" jsonText=JSONGoesHere
```

although depending on your command line shell it might be difficult to pass in JSON with quotes directly. Perhaps use JSON in a file and pass in the file name/URI and then use `unparsed-text($json-file)`.

I also wonder why you seem to use Saxon 9.7, the first Saxon version to implement the XSLT 3 and XPath 3.1 standard is Saxon 9.8 so it would be better to use Saxon 9.8 or later to work with features specified in XSLT 3 and/or XPath 3.1.

Comment: How to get pure `XML` file when converting from `JSON`. I have getting with `map` and `array` element in the XML file.

Comment: @user49758, XML is XML, I don't know what you consider "pure" XML. You are supposed to take that result of  `json-to-xml` and push it with `<xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/>` to your custom templates performing any transformation of the format the `json-to-xml` function returns to the format you want or need. The format is documented in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json-to-xml-mapping and of course for a start you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="json-to-xml($jsonText)"/>` to see the result, then write templates to transform it, either as a separate step or directly.

Comment: How to avoid `map` and `array` tags?. I have expecting final `XML` looks like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root><analystId>Test</analystId><jobId></jobId><profileData><allAuthorCoverage>false</allAuthorCoverage><assetClasses><code>Test1</code></assetClasses></profileData></root>`.

Comment: @user49758, that is a simple XML to XML transformation that you should be able to implement reading any XSLT tutorial, if you encounter problems, then ask a new question with the necessary details and where you are stuck.

Comment: I would like to convert `json2XML`. When i have used above `XSLT` it will give `map` and `array` elements. How to ignore that tags?

Comment: @user49758, as I said, please raise that issue in a separate question if you can't solve it yourself.

Comment: @Margin: Please find the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096727/json-to-xml-conversing-using-xslt-3-0

Answer (score 0):

I have using Saxon 9.9(HE) and my Updatd `XSL` is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" /> 
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:param name="jsonText"/>
  <xsl:param name="input" select="'simple3.json'"/>

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template> 

 <xsl:template name="init">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(unparsed-text($input))" mode="copy"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node() | @*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my Command prompt shell:
`c:transform -it:"init" -xsl:simple3.xsl -o:out.xml`

Thanks for Margin Honnen suggestion. It's working fine.